# no such object in table when calling registry.lookup

Tags: java, rmi

i am having a trouble when trying to run communication between server and client using RMI. My code is attached below. Server runs fine, i can see listening port in list of pc ports, client fails on registry.lookup. I didnt find any similar problem. Please help.

Server:

```
public class Main {

private static int port = Registry.REGISTRY_PORT; 
private static Registry registry;
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

   if (args.length == 1) {
        try {
                port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Port number is not valid!");
    System.exit(0);
            }
}

    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
        System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
String name = "DBInterface";

    System.out.println("Starting server.");

    try {        
        DBInterface DBInterface = new DBClass();
        DBInterface stub = (DBInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(DBInterface, 5000); 
        registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
        registry.rebind(name, stub);
    }
    catch (RemoteException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Server succesfully started.");

}
```

}

Client:

```
public class Client {

private static String ipAddress = "localhost";
private static int port = Registry.REGISTRY_PORT;
private static String confFile = "";
public static DBInterface dbServer = null;
public static String name = "DBInterface";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Starting client.");

    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
        System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());


    if (args.length == 3) {
        try {
            ipAddress = args[0];
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            confFile = args[2];
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Port number is not valid!");
    System.exit(0);
        }
}
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Some parameter is missing!");
        System.out.println("Valid parameters are: IP(0) Port(1) Config_file_name(2).");
    }

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> commands = Tools.loadConfigFile(confFile);
    Iterator<ArrayList<String>> commandsIterator = commands.iterator();
    Registry registry;

try {
        registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(ipAddress, port);    
        dbServer = (DBInterface) registry.lookup(name);  //code fails here                   
} catch (RemoteException e) { 
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());  //"no such object in table" is printed on the screen
} catch (NotBoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}        
    Tools tools = new Tools(dbServer);
```

...

Comment: It's hard to believe you get this when calling `lookup()`. Are you sure you aren't getting it when calling the remote method on the object resulting from the lookup?

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, i am afraid pretty sure. I run server from command line, than i debug client in netbeans. I go line by line, and "dbServer = (DBInterface) registry.lookup(name);" fails in try block, catch prints "no such object in table". Program continues, because i forgot to place system.exit in catch statement, but it fails later when calling remote method.

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace. Edit it into your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is basically impossible. That exception means that the stub you are using, in this case a Registry, no longer refers to a live exported object in the target JVM. However as Registry stubs are created locally there is no opportunity for them to expire at all. The only mechanism would be the Registry you created exiting, but the static Registry reference should prevent that.

I would change a few things though:

```
    DBInterface stub = (DBInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(DBInterface, 5000); 
    registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
```

Reverse these two lines, and use `port` for both the Registry and the export. You don't need two ports. Also, in all your catch blocks, never just suppress the exception message in favour of your own. You should always at least log the actual exception message.

Comment: Impossible, but happening :) However your advice gave me a direction, and code is now working. It was probably because of two ports. One was default 1099, and other manually set was 5000. Code failed, when i used port 5000. I switched those 2 lines above, as you advised me. Than i made client to connect to port 1099 instead of 5000, and code is not failing anymore. Thank you for advice and have a nice day.

Comment: Using port 5000 in the client was the problem. There was no Registry running on port 5000. It was always on port 1099. It wasn't apparent from your client code because the port comes from the command line.